# Unable to read the full output redirected from Console application - SVN Update automation

Tags: c#, .net, svn, console

I am trying to automate the update procedure for the svn update using the console application. I use the following code below.

```
ProcessStartInfo svnUpdate = new ProcessStartInfo();
svnUpdate.Arguments =  string.Format("update \"{0}\" -r {1}", destination,  revisionNo);
svnUpdate.FileName = "svn.exe";
svnUpdate.CreateNoWindow = true;
svnUpdate.UseShellExecute = false;
svnUpdate.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
svnUpdate.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
svnUpdate.RedirectStandardError = true;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = svnUpdate;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.Start();
svnOutPut = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();

if (p.HasExited)
{
Console.WriteLine("Received Output Test : " + svnOutPut);
}
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

The above code works fine if there are no errors returned with update command. If there are some errors I am able to get only the First line of the outpput returned but when I set the code below the console gives me the full error text.

```
svnUpdate.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
svnUpdate.RedirectStandardError = false;
```

Sample outpput when I have the Redirection to false.

```
Updating 'C:\TestSvnRepo':
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svnrepositoryAdd/svn/TestSvnRepo'
svn: E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/TestSvnRepo'

svn: E720003: Additional errors:
svn: E720003: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

Sample output received in string when I have the redirection to True.

```
Updating: 'C:\TestSvnRepo':
```

Comment: Maybe I missed the question?  What do you want to happen?

Comment: I am trying to read the output returned from Svn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the output that you're missing is sent through `STDERR`, not `STDOUT`. In your code, you're only looking at `STDOUT` (`svnOutPut = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`)

You need to read `STDERR` as well -  `p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();`

As an aside, I would recommend that rather than automating `svn.exe` and adding both the application and environment dependency (IOW, your app requires that `svn.exe` be present on the system **and** be in either `%PATH%` or a known absolute path that you specify), you use [SharpSVN](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) which provides a .NET implementation of the SVN API itself.

Comment: Thanks that worked!! And by the way the program was a sample created from the main. I am using the absolute path for the application.

Comment: You're still left with that external dependency though, which is the point I was making there. SharpSVN integrates much better with most apps, with the bonus of not having to spawn additional processes and capture/parse the output.